# Вернуть md5 к исходному значению на С

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите какой-нибудь декриптор или что-нибудь в этом роде на Си для md5.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы шифровка md5 превращалась в то, что было до шифрования. Возможно ли такое в принципе, и если нет, то почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MD5 - это не "шифрование", это хэш-функция. Основное требование к [криптографическим хэш-функциям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) - необратимость.

Если бы хэши были обратимы, то архиваторы и прочие алгоритмы сжатия стали бы не нужны. Например, я посчитал хэш от терабайтного файла. Получил `79a2520f22b9e1526ff93176029603b8`. Вы считаете что можно эту строчку расшифровать обратно в тот же терабайт информации?

Максимум, что можно сделать для MD5 - найти [коллизию (второй прообраз)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) - строчку, для которой MD5 выдаст такое же значение. Это можно сделать или по готовым словарям (если есть подозрение что строчка - это пароль вида 12345), или с использованием радужных таблиц.

Но никакой гарантии что вы получите при этом именно оригинальную строку нет. Точнее, вы с некоторой вероятностью получите оригинальную строку, если она была короткой. Но вы точно получите неоригинальную строку, а просто коллизию, если оригинал был достаточно длинным.

Если поиска коллизии для вас достаточно - поищите [готовую опен-сорс реализацию  работы с радужными таблицами](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=md5+rainbow&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults), например [MD5Rainbow](https://github.com/xurubin/MD5Rainbow).

Comment: Ну просто в интернете есть разные сайты на которых есть ввести сумму например какой нибудь стринг переменной то они вернут нормальное значение. Так же и в программе у меня. Пользователь вводит пароль, он шифруется в МД5 и сохраняется в файл отдельный.Это все на Си происходит. Нужно сделать так что бы потом обратно вот этот код превратился в читальное слово что бы вывести его

Comment: @OverLoader Эти сайты выдают коллизии, а не оригинальные строки. Дописал в ответ.

Comment: @OverLoader, если вы найдёте в интернете сайт, который сможет «извлечь» строку «это невозможно, карл» из полученного мною сейчас хэша `$1$JNU2zztq$Yvyky8eSm9GyAdQPxKR5T0`, то вам имеет смысл срочно связаться с владельцем сайта и предложить совместно поучаствовать в получении нобелевской премии.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спешу разочаровать: за математику нобелевскую премию не дают.

Comment: @Discord, не убивайте последнюю надежду у автора вопроса! пусть думает, что «расхэшировать хэш» и получить за это нобелевскую премию — вполне возможно. кстати, мне кажется, что подобное открытие явно не относится к области математики.

Comment: @Discord: ex falso quodlibet

Comment: @PashaPash не верю, что это был терабайтный файл:) во первых, вряд ли такое есть у Вас, а во вторых - там захешированно обычное слово 'impossible'.  Коллизия? не думаю (с) какая-то телевизионная программа:)

Comment: @KoVadim у меня есть терабайтный файл. но у меня не хватило терпения дождаться расчета md5 для него :)

Comment: ах да, у меня есть и больше файл, /dev/random называется, но он медленно отдает, терабайт где то за пол года отдаст. Но честный терабайтовый файл где то за 3.5 часа переварит, если файловая система не подкачает.

Так что я думаю, что честного файла все таки нет:)

Comment: @KoVadim ок, поймали за руку. не терабайт. Всего 934 Gb. Хотите нотариально заверенный скриншот?

Comment: запаковывайте и выкладывайте, только так, только хардкор:)

Answer (score 3):

Обратное действие в md5 не возможно.
Получить оригинал можно только методом перебора, то есть брутом или по словарю.
Перебирать варианты, md5 хеш каждого нужно сравнить с имеющимся хешом md5. Тот который будет равен вашему хешу, возможно будет ваш оригинал! (возможно! но не факт!).
А на сайтах про которые вы говорите имеются словари с готовым оригиналом и готовым мд5, они просто проверяют есть ли в их словарях такие хеши, и смотрят к ним записанные ранее оригиналы строк. Но опять таки тоже не факт что это ваш хэш.